Sourcetree/Android Studio: Resolving conflict in MR from GitLab
I have an question about resolving MRs from GitLab using SourceTree and/or Android Studio directly.
I was used to resolve MRs using SourceTree only.
Example: I have feature branch which should be merged into develop one with merge conflicts.
So I just switched to develop branch, clicked "Merge" in SorceTree and picked commit from feature branch which should be merged into develop. Then I got files with merge conflicts so I just right-clicked them and opened each file in Merge Tool within Android Studio where I could individually accept theirs/ours lines/conflicts.
But with this project I'm working at, develop is protected branch so the only way how to push something into it is via GitLab MR and resolving conflicts there on website (using merge tool from GitLab which is really bad).
Is there any way or workaround how I can just pull MR from GitLab via SourceTree or Android Studio and use regular Merge Tool which I'm used to?
Currently I'm using Android Studio Koala Feature Drop
Within Merge Requests tab in left menu I can just observe MRs from GitLab when I'm logged into GitLab acc with Personal Access Token but I cant resolve MRs (I don't have any button there to resolve it, just warning that there are merge conflicts)
